# Problems with custom form validator in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I create custom form validator for checking equality of password, I mean it checks if the passwords are matching. I can't get a real true or false in my html(variable=signupForm.valid ). Maybe I need to pass on different way controlValuesAreEqual in my form, or there is problem with imports all these forms and validators?

Ts file:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UntypedFormGroup, UntypedFormBuilder, Validators, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss'],
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  public signupForm!: UntypedFormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['',Validators.required],
      validators: this.controlValuesAreEqual('password', 'confirmPassword')
    
    });
  }
  private controlValuesAreEqual(controlNameA: string, controlNameB: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const formGroup = control as FormGroup
      const valueOfControlA = formGroup.get(controlNameA)?.value
      const valueOfControlB = formGroup.get(controlNameB)?.value

      if (valueOfControlA === valueOfControlB) {
        return null
      } else {
        return { valuesDoNotMatch: true }
      }


    }
  }
  signUp() {
    this.http
      .post<any>('http://localhost:3000/signupUsers', this.signupForm.value)
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.signupForm.reset(), this.router.navigate(['login']);
        },
        error: (e) => alert('Something went wrong'),
      });
  }
}
```

And HTML is here

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="card" style="padding: 20px">
    <h2 class="text-center">Please Sign Up!</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="signUp()">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
        <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="email" matInput placeholder="E-Mail" />
        <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="name" />
        <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input
          type="password"
          formControlName="password"
          matInput
          placeholder="password"
        />
        <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
        <mat-label>Confirm Password</mat-label>
        <input
          type="password"
          formControlName="confirmPassword"
          matInput
          placeholder="password"
        />
        <mat-hint align="start">
          <strong>{{ signupForm.valid }}</strong>
        </mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="w-100">
        Sign Up
      </button>
    </form>
    <a style="text-decoration: none; margin-top: 10px" routerLink="/login"
      >Already registered? Click to Login</a
    >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see that is: this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({..},{validators:this.controlValuesAreEqual('password', 'confirmPassword')}), -the "{validators:..} is a second argument of the method "group"-

Answer (score 0):

Include this method in your component so that password and confirmed password mismatch error can be emitted to your template.

```
get passwordMatchError() {
    return (
        this.signupForm.getError('valuesDoNotMatch') &&
        this.signupForm.get('confirmPassword')?.touched
    );
}
```

Place the following code under confirm password `mat-form-field` section so that the mismatch error can be shown.

```
<mat-error *ngIf="passwordMatchError">Password and confirmed password do not match.</mat-error>
```

Comment: I still don't get anything if the pass don't match

Comment: Is it possible for you to reproduce the issue on Stackblitz, so that we can investigate?

Comment: Here is https://github.com/AleksandarRadinkovic/user-app-angular but if you want to login you need to start json server  
npm install -g json-server and to find folder api and start json-server --watch db.json